# Calculating global horizontal irradiance (GHI) from surface solar radiation downwards from the ERA5 data

Tags: solar-radiation

I have some hourly data of surface solar radiation downwards (SSRD) measured in J/m^2 from the ERA5 dataset (ECMWF - European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts).

How can I convert these to global horizontal irradiance (GHI) in kWh/m^2? Is it just simply SSRD/3600000?

I know the formula for GHI is:

[image]

where:

DNI = direct normal irradiance

DHI = diffuse horizontal irradiance

z = solar zenith angle

Is SSRD sufficient for calculating GHI or do I need other data?

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [ERA5 description](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels?tab=overview), variable SSRD ...

> *...is the model equivalent of what would be measured by a **pyranometer** (an instrument used for measuring solar radiation) at the surface.*

Therefore it is equivalent to GHI.

Your formula for units conversion (J/m2 to kWh/m2) is correct (SSRD/3600000).

Just maybe the better term here is *irradia**tion*** (because in this case it is an aggregation over 1 hour). *Irradian**ce*** refers rather to instantaneous values.